# How to access test-output directory that Reporter uses from ITestListener

Tags: java, testng

We are using IReporter's generateReport() method to create a custom report. At the start of a run, We need to delete the report file if it exists.

Reason we need to do this is because we are utilizing SkipException inside ITestListener's onStart() method - we need to fail/stop the test run if certain exceptions are raised.  If this happens, then generateReport() is never called, leaving the existing custom-report in place, oftentimes creating confusion.

How do I access the same outputDirectory that is being used in generateReport(), from ITestListener?  I can get ITestContext's outputDirectory, but that leads me to a subfolder of Reporter's outputDirectory.

```
public class CustomTestListener implements ITestListener {

    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext ctx) {

        // This returns a child directory of the actual directory we want
        // String outputDir = ctx.getOutputDirectory();

        // This is null, how would i access from ITestContext?
        // XMLReporter x = new XMLReporter();
        // String outputDir = x.getOutputDirectory();

        // method that would delete the file
        String reportFile = outputDir + "/" + GlobalConstants.REPORT_FILE;
        deleteFile (reportFile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out one solution, this works for me:

```
String outputDir = ctx.getOutputDirectory() + "/../"
```